# Oracle Sql Developer connections storage

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Where does Oracle SQL Developer-3.2.20 store connections?

It used to be in `IDEconnections.xml` but in the latest version I do not see this file.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using 3.1.07 and it's stored under:

```
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system3.1.07.42
\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48\connections.xml
```

Replace the sqldeveloper version with your own and you should be able to find the correct folder.

Else you can always right-click on `Connections` in the Connections view of SQLDeveloper and select `Export connections`.

Answer (score 2):

SqlDeveloper stores all the connections in a file named

```
connections.xml
```

In windows XP you can find the file in location

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\SQL Developer\systemX.X.X.X.X\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.X.X.X.X.X.X.X\connections.xml
```

In Windows 7 you will find it in location

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemX.X.X.X.X\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.X.X.X.X.X.X.X\connections.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2023, in SQL Developer 19.1.0, I see this in -

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system19.1.0.nnn.pppp\o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.json
```

In other words, they have moved from XML to JSON.  Also, the "*o.jdeveloper.db.connection*" folder is now 'bare' (i.e., does not have any release numbers following it).